# Relative vs Subjective

Tags: meaning

Can anyone tell the difference between **relative** and **subjective** ?

Does **subjective** mean "*only my opinion matters*", while **relative** means "*it could change*"?

I can't really understand the difference.

Comment: I can't really understand the question.

Comment: *Does subjective mean "only my opinion matters", while relative means "it could change"?*  No and no.  *Relative* means *in comparison*, for example, if you say, This question is difficult, I could ask you what you are comparing it with ("Difficult relative to what?").  *Subjective* means *based on your personal opinion or experience*, for example, if you say, "This is the best textbook for studying algebra," I could say, "That's a subjective statement!"  You could then respond that it's not just your opinion, the book won various prizes.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is close, but I'll try my best to explain the difference.

[**Subjective**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subjective) :

That would be a **subject** or something which relates to one

> From M-W : *(adj)* 1:  of, relating to, or constituting a subject

Or something which depends on this subject's perception

> From M-W : *(adj)* 3a: characteristic of or belonging to reality as perceived rather than as independent of mind :  phenomenal — compare [objective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objective)

Example : Your opinion is subjective.

One's opinion about something depends on the knowledge that person has.

[**Relative**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relative) :

It means the notion depends on the relation of multiple subjects.

> From M-W : *(adj)* 3:  not absolute or independent

Example : Your speed is relative.

From your point of view, your speed is null. But from your friend's point of view, which is running, your speed is 5 km/h.

---

It might be easier to understand by looking at antonyms :

- Relative / Absolute
- Subjective / Objective